# SSH Command to change permission of subfolder

Tags: ssh

I currently use the following two commands:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I am under the impression that one changes all directories and subdirectories to 755 and the other changes all files and files in subfolders to 644

I would like to pick and choose the subdirectories.

For example:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {/sudirectoryOfCurrentDirectory} \;
```

How do I pick a subdirectory and subdirectories in that subdirectory?
How do I pick a subdirectory and all files in that subdirectory and it's subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but when I look other answers they looks so complex according to your need.

You requested, you want to change given directory's subdirectories ? Isn't it ?

It basically means.

```
find ./yoursubdirectory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following would list every directory and ask if you want to `chmod 755` it. Answer `y` to chmod it.

```
find . -type d | xargs -p -n 1 chmod 755
```

You could use grep to include patterns:

```
find . -type d | grep subdirectoryOfCurrentDirectory | xargs chmod 755
```

Or you could use grep to exclude patterns:

```
find . -type d | grep -v subdirectoryOfCurrentDirectory | xargs chmod 755
```

Comment: so if i was in public_html and there a subfolder called /mySecondSite
and it had multiple directories in it, the following code would change all the directories inside of public_html/mySecondSite  as well as public_html/mySecondSite to 755?
find . -type d | grep mySecondSite | xargs chmod 755

Comment: It would change the permissions of any directory with the text "mySecondSite" in the name.

Comment: Try `find . -type d | grep mySecondSite | xargs -n 1 echo`.  Then play around with the grep statement to narrow the directories listed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do the following:**

---

To pick a subdirectory, and all directories in that subdirectory, recursively:

```
chmod <permission> `find path/to/subdirectory -type d`
```

---

To pick a subdirectory, and all files in that subdirectory, recursively:

```
chmod <permission> `find path/to/subdirectory -type f`
```

---

**Example:**

```
chmod 755 `find name_of_subdir -type d`    # all directories in subdir
chmod 755 `find name_of_subdir -type f`    # all files in subdir
```